# Одно событие на несколько кнопок

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Есть три кнопки, при нажатии на любую из них у неё самой поменяется цвет/надпись/ect. Не могу додуматься, как это организовать.

```
import sys,gui
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *




class Window(QMainWindow, gui.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.Button_1.clicked.connect(self.func)
        self.Button_2.clicked.connect(self.func)
        self.Button_3.clicked.connect(self.func)

    def ChangeSomething(self):
        #а тут что писать? как передать информацию о той кнопке, на которую нажали?
        #не писать же мне для каждой кнопки отдельную функцию?






if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Window()
    form.show()
    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй метод [QObject.sender():](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender)

```
def ChangeSomething(self):
    btn = self.sender()
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
import sys                                            # ??? ,gui
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Window(QMainWindow):                            # ???, gui.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
#        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.button_1 = QPushButton(
            'button_1', objectName='button_1', clicked=self.change_something)
        self.button_1.setCheckable(True)                                 # !!! +++
        self.button_1.setAutoExclusive(True)                             # !!! +++
        self.button_2 = QPushButton(
            'button_2', objectName='button_2', clicked=self.change_something)
        self.button_2.setCheckable(True) 
        self.button_2.setAutoExclusive(True)
        self.button_3 = QPushButton(
            'button_3', objectName='button_3', clicked=self.change_something)
        self.button_3.setCheckable(True) 
        self.button_3.setAutoExclusive(True)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.button_1)
        layout.addWidget(self.button_2)
        layout.addWidget(self.button_3)
        
        self.buttons = (self.button_1, self.button_2, self.button_3)

    def change_something(self):
        for btn in self.buttons:
            if  btn.isChecked():
                btn.setText(f"Нажата {btn.objectName()}")
                btn.setStyleSheet("""
                    background-color: #00FF00; 
                    color: #0000FF;
                    font-size: 14px;
                """)
            else:
                btn.setText(f"{btn.objectName()}")
                btn.setStyleSheet("")
                

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Window()
    form.show()
    app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]